# How can I only print the letters of a string in python?

Tags: python

I have a program which allows the user to input a sentence and it's supposed to output the first 10 letters in lowercase. The code I've got prints the letters and the spaces. Is there any way to make it only print the letters in lowercase? Thanks.

```
letters = str(input("Enter a sentence: "))
print(letters[0:10].lower())
```

Comment: Are we talking ASCII-only here?

Comment: I'd like the program to only output (if it's there) the 26 letters of the alphabet and the numbers 1234567890

Comment: Are you expecting letter to occur in result only once or just letters in same order without spaces?

Comment: If I inputted: "Hello, I'm a human" then I'd like the program to output "Hello, I am a h"

Comment: 10 letters and any spaces or punctuation

Comment: But it contains letter in upper case -_-

Comment: @Olvin oops, typo. It's meant to be "hello, i am a h"

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want the spaces or not?

Comment: So, do you want to count 10 letters/digits, but print also spaces and puntuaction in between?

Comment: @grooveplex To be perfectly honest I've confused myself. Shehan Ishanka posted an answer which is working for spaces, so I'll probably use that.

Comment: @Valentino in a nutshell. That's exactly it.

Comment: I think it will be much better if you can provide a example/examples with the expected output

Comment: @Shehan Ishanka okay. Here's an example: Input: "Hello, I am a human" Output: "hello, i am a h"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code:**

```
import string

s = "Hello, I'm a human"
result = ""
letters = 0
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits

for c in s.lower():
    result += c
    if c in alphabet:
        letters += 1
        if letters > 9:
            break
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
hello, i'm a hu
```

Comment: This is the sort of thing I need but the user has to input a sentence

Comment: @Mrmongoose64, replace assignment of string with `input()`, is that a big deal? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
inp = str(input("Enter a sentence: "))
letters = re.sub(r'[^ A-Za-z0-9]', '', inp)
print(letters[0:10].lower())
```